# A method I created for link shortening gives a complement error at the time of initialization

Tags: flutter, dart, url

When starting an asynchronous method that I use to shorten long links, it always gives a complement error. I need help on what the problem is.

My Code

```
getLinkUrl() async {
final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse("https://cleanuri.com//api/v1/shorten"),
    body: {'url': controller.text});
var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
print(result);
```

}

ERROR
[image: Error Details]

Comment: That server doesn't supply any CORS headers on its response, so you cannot call it directly from a Javascript application running in a browser (or Dart application compiled to Javascript).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the same problem persists. However, I couldn't understand the code block you wrote at the bottom.  await shortenUrl(
  'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658684/a-method-i-created-for-link-shortening-gives-a-complement-error-at-the-time-of-i');

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the below code? It worked for me.

```
Future<void> shortenUrl(String longUrl) async {
  var url = Uri.parse('https://cleanuri.com//api/v1/shorten');
  var response = await http.post(url, body: {'url': longUrl});
  print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
  print('Response body: ${json.decode(response.body)}');
}


await shortenUrl(
  'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658684/a-method-i-created-for-link-shortening-gives-a-complement-error-at-the-time-of-i');
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Did you get this to work in Dartpad?

Comment: Well, can you give us some information on how to do this with the right logic?

Comment: @Ademköseoğlu You won't be able to do this in Flutter Web because of CORS, as already stated. This is why I asked if this solution was tested in Dartpad (spoiler alert - it won't work).

Comment: @RichardHeap Ya it won't work in Dartpad. Also I didn't realize from the question that the issue was with the Flutter web.

Comment: @RichardHeap thanks it worked :)